# Double-clicking a universal data link (.udl) file doesn’t open Data Link Properties dialog box

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-association

Ok folks,

I'm pulling my hairs out on this one so hoped the wisdom of the crowd can help me out here and keep me sane...

I have a new workstation with 64-bit Windows 7 on it and I can't use [Universal Data Link (.udl) Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e(v=vs.71).aspx) anymore.

What I mean is, when I double-click on any file with .udl extension I don't get the Data Link Properties dialog box as expected, but instead a Windows alert "windows can't open this file":
[image: Windows dialog]

Normally the .udl File extension should "Open with" OLE DB Core Services but that's clearly not happening here.

I tried to fix the file type mapping, but since it opens with a dll I'm not sure how.

This is how I can start the Data Link Properties dialog box from a command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\syswow64\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll",OpenDSLFile C:\localdata\TestWin7Connection.udl
```

Any suggestion how I can fix this?